# GeoExplorer cannot upload shapefiles into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I have installed OpenGeo 4.1 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 following the [official instructions](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/installation/ubuntu/install.html).

I then followed the tutorial [Load your data with GeoExplorer](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/webmaps/easypublish/load.html).

I was able to zip and upload a few shapefiles. The layers show at the right geographical extents. However, what I didn't get is the following, as said in  the tutorial

> When deployed alongside GeoServer and PostGIS, GeoExplorer will
>   convert spatial files into PostGIS tables, and then serve that data
>   through GeoServer. This process is seamless; all you need to do is
>   supply the data.

The shapefiles I uploaded didn't become PostGIS tables as advertised. Instead, when inspecting the uploaded layers in GeoServer, I see that the data source under "Connection Parameters" for the layers are still something like this (a shapefile):

```
file:uploads/tmp6091327178585086343/nr_adm0/nr_adm0.shp
```

I am able to access PostreSQL from pgAdmin, as well as from command line with

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

I was wondering if someone has had a similar problem and know where the issue might be with the link from GeoExplorer to PostGIS?